# Problem with proof of almost sure divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let's define
$$P(X_n=1)=\frac1n,\;P(X_n=0)=1-\frac1n$$
$(X_n)$ are independent.
I want to show that does not exist X such that : 
${\displaystyle {\overset {}{X_{n}\,{\xrightarrow {\mathrm {a.s.} }}\,X.}}}$

We know that 
$$
X_{n} \xrightarrow{\mathrm{a.s.}} X
\iff \mathbb{P}\left(\omega:\lim_{n\to \infty}X_n(\omega)=X(\omega)\right)=1. 
$$
$(X_n)$ is constant sequence so the limit of $(X_n)$ is $0$ or $1$.
Let's consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\omega:X_n(\omega)=1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n=\infty.$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(\omega:X_n(\omega)=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1-\frac1n=\infty.$

So by the second Borell-Cantelli lemma i get :

${\displaystyle P\left(\bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty }\bigcup _{k=n}^{\infty }(\omega:X_n(\omega)=0)\right)=1.}$

${\displaystyle P\left(\bigcap _{n=1}^{\infty }\bigcup _{k=n}^{\infty }(\omega:X_n(\omega)=1)\right)=1.}$.

And now i want to tell that $(X_n)$ cannot has limit because he oscillates between $0$ and $1$. Am i thinking correctly ?

Comment: It was very good to use Borel-Cantelli here: You have proved that $(X_n)_n$ does not converge to $X=0$ almost surely. On the other hand, you know that $(X_n)_n$ converges to $Y=0$ in probability. So, by uniqueness of limits, if $(X_n)_n$ converged almost surely, the limit would have to be $X=0$.

Comment: By the way, why do you say that the sequence is constant? It's not the case since each $X_n$ takes two distinct values with positive probability.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's my mistake, i mean that if $(X_n)$ has a limit, it has to exist $n_0$ that for $n\ge n_0$ $(X_n)$ is constant.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, with this remark I think your argument also completes the proof.

Comment: To apply 2nd Borell-Cantelli, you need *independence* of $(X_n)_n$.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You posted the same question earlier and I have given a counterexmaple. If you don't understand it you can ask for more details. Don't clutter MSE by repeating questions.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to write that $(X_n)$ are independent.